# Issue with Django Inline form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have attached TestInline in the FoobarAdmin, this thing works well but i want logged in user to be pre-populated for the added_by field

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Test(models.Model):

    description = models.TextField()
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='added_by',)

class TestInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Test
        extra = 1

class FoobarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TestInline,]

admin.site.register(Foobar, FoobarAdmin)
```

Please let me know if its possible to have user prepopulated for the added_by field

Answer (score 1):

See [prepopulated_fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) in the admin docs.

If I understand what you need correctly, I think [this article by James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/) tackles the issue pretty well.

Finally (in case you haven't seen them), there are [two other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset) [informative posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529890/django-how-to-preopopluate-admin-form-fields) on prepopulating admin fields.

Comment: I already checked but the problem is added_by field is a foreignKey to user and the docs says "prepopulated_fields doesn't accept DateTimeField, ForeignKey, nor ManyToManyField fields."

Can you please help me out of this?

Comment: Seems the favoured way is to override the relevant admin form with one that uses Javascript/JQuery to do what you need. There are several StackOverflow posts on this, and here is one that seems most useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799857/filtering-foreign-keys-with-ajax-in-django-admin

Comment: However (and I haven't tried this, so just wondering) perhaps you could try using 'default' instead: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default