# Add button for child model in Django admin

Tags: python, django

Django 1.11. I have 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

In the `Foo` detail page in the Django admin, I list all child `Bar`s underneath the `Foo` details:

```
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def bars(self):
        html = ''
        bs = self.bar_set.all()
        for b in bs:
            html += '<a href="%s">%s</a><br>' % (reverse('admin:app_bar_change', args=(b.id,)), b.name)
        html += '<a href="%s">Add a bar</button>' % (reverse('admin:app_bar_add'))
        return html

    bars.allow_tags = True
    fields = ('name', bars)
    readonly_fields = (bars,)
```

As you can see, I also add a button to add a new `Bar`. This works, but what I want is to automatically prepopulate the `Foo` dropdown when adding a new `Bar`. I.e. I want to add a `Bar` to the currently open `Foo`. How can I do this in Django?

Comment: You can have a link to the change page of each inline by using [InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link). If you do not want to use inlines, it is better to have the foreignkey in `bar` pointing to `foo` instead of the opposite, and this will automatically use the necessary widget and javascript addons to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @raratiru As I understand it, the foreign key in `bar` is already pointing to `foo`, no?

Comment: Indeed! I meant the opposite, the foreignkey from `foo` to point at `bar`. From Django 2.0 there is also a new feature called [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields). You still can hack around and implement what you want, even override the [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and define a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) but I am not sure it is worth, even if it worked.

Comment: My problem with switching the foreign key is that a `Foo` can have many `Bar`s. Appreciate the advice though!

Comment: I will give it a try at home to see if defining a custom field with a many-to-many widget in the ModelForm could lead to a viable result. Is it out of the question to create `bar = models.ManyToManyField()` in `Foo`?

Comment: @raratiru I've found a hacky solution (see my answer below). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this django allows you to include [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) in your admin class. For example the following would display the related objects in a table without displaying the form to change values for the `name` field;

```
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar
    fields = (
        'name'
    )
    readonly_fields = (
        'name'
    )
    show_change_link = True

@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', )
    inlines = [
        BarInline,
    ]
```

By setting `show_change_link` you can display a change link for the inline object which I believe is what you're really looking for here.

> Django provides two subclasses of `InlineModelAdmin` and they are:
>
> - `TabularInline`
> - `StackedInline`
>
> The difference between these two is merely the template used to render them.

If these inlines don't meet your needs, you could just create your own to use a custom template.

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import InlineModelAdmin


class ListInlineAdmin(InlineModelAdmin):
    template = 'admin/edit_inline/list.html'
```

Then in the new `list.html` template you can get it to display the object name & change URL as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I know about inlines, but I don't want dozens of large forms underneath stacked up on the same page. Hence the list of links to separate pages.

Comment: @GluePear Ok, probably wise to just implement your own inline class with a different template, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @GluePear The solution with the custom inline template keeps separately the business logic from the design logic. Therefore it has more chances to survive heavy loads or even a possible heavy refactoring. (Django update)

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973380). Pre-populated fields can be specified in the URL's query string. So my code now looks like this:

```
if self.id:    
    html += '<a href="%s?foo=%d">Add a bar</a>' % (reverse('admin:app_bar_add'), self.id)
```

Edit: I need to check first that the instance has an `id`, i.e. that it has already been saved.

Comment: Will this work if the current `Foo` instance is not saved?

Comment: Very good point. In that case I will have to hide the button until the instance has been saved.