# How to make prepopulated field with model relationship field?

Tags: python, django

I try to add *prepopulated_fields* at my admin class like this:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('get_trainer_name',)}

    def get_trainer_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.get_full_name()
```

but got en error

```
ERRORS:
<class 'trainers.admin.ProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to 'get_trainer_name', which is not an attribute of 'trainers.Profile'.
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Also I tryed to make this another way - to override models save method :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.user.get_full_name())
            super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it gave no result..

In accordance with the advice @Tiger_Mike I tryed to make at ProfileAdmin

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ProfileAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    if not obj.slug:
        obj.slug = slugify(obj.user.get_full_name())
    return form
```

And it doesnt work with slugify, but good work without slugify

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529890/django-how-to-prepopulate-admin-form-fields. Specifically the answer that overrides get_form

Comment: @Tiger_Mike good advice, I tried and its good working, but without slugify. If I add sluggify, nothing happens

Comment: would you mind updating your question with your latest code? Cheers

Comment: Please try ```form.base_fields['slug'].initial = slugify(obj.user.get_full_name())```

Comment: unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: I found that the problem is that the name is written in Cyrillic, after adding the argument `allow_unicode = True`  to the slugify function, everything worked with  `get_form()`

Comment: Good find. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look through the admin documentaion and [this hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data) should do the job.