# Wagtail - how to preopulate fields in admin form?

Tags: django, wagtail

I would like to pre-populate fields in wagtail page admin. Particularly I would like to take username of currently logged admin/editor user and fill it in the form as a string. A simplified version of my page looks like this:

```
class ItemPage(Page):

    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('author'),
    ]
```

I do not want to set a default value in the author field in the model - it should be user specific.

I do not want to use the `save` method or signal after the model is saved/altered. The user should see what is there and should have the ability to change it. Also, the pages will be generated automatically without the admin interface.

I think that I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322706/3960850 but not in Django, but with the Wagtail ModelAdmin.

How to achieve this in Wagtail?

Comment: FWIW, we had a similar requirement and found that there wasn't a good way to hook into Wagtail's 'create page' view to achieve this. I've now opened a pull request https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/5353 to support this, which will hopefully make it into a future release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example based on gasmans comment and the documentation that accompanies the new code they linked:

```
from wagtail.admin.views.pages import CreatePageView, register_create_page_view
from myapp.models import ItemPage

class ItemPageCreateView(CreatePageView):
    def get_page_instance(self):
        page = super().get_page_instance()
        page.author = 'Some default value'
        return page

register_create_page_view(ItemPage, ItemPageCreateView.as_view())
```

You could also do this by overriding the models `init` method, but the above is much nicer

```
class ItemPage(Page):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            author = kwargs['owner'].username
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            pass
        else:
            self.author = author
```

Comment: Note: this no longer works when checked recently in Wagtail 2.7+

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and found out, how to do it.

**Task** There is a blog (build with Wagtail) allowing multiple article authors. An article page also exposes details of the author (profile picture, job, introduction of the author) who wrote an article.

**Solution** So extend the default user model with the fields which should be added

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html

and access the user in the template (through owner).

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.models.Page.owner