# How to modify Page model view in wagtail admin?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Background: I would like to enhance a page instance during an admin page view with some admin request related information (some pre-population in general). Basically I would need some function like "get_queryset", but not for list view, just for edit view.

In my older question related to a similar problem: [Wagtail - how to preopulate fields in admin form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480823/wagtail-how-to-preopulate-fields-in-admin-form) I was provided with instructions to use something called

> CreatePageView

However, I cannot import it. Furthermore, I cannot even found any mention about that in google if I search:

> Wagtail +CreatePageView

The closest thing I found is https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/create_edit_delete_views.html but the page also states:

> NOTE: modeladmin only provides ‘create’, ‘edit’ and ‘delete’
>   functionality for non page type models (i.e. models that do not extend
>   wagtailcore.models.Page). If your model is a ‘page type’ model,
>   customising any of the following will not have any effect

I am quite confused. What should I do if I need to customize the admin view for Page model extension?

I studied the wagtail source codes for Model.admin and Page and I have not found any way. Any ideas?

The related code simplified:

wagtail hooks:

```
class ItemAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    pass

    # some function override here maybe?
```

models:

```
class ItemPage(Page):

    pass

    # override for a function that gives data to the admin view maybe here?
```

**Edit**

As suggested in comments, it is possible to modify the admin page form during creation:

```
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm

class ItemPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, parent_page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data, files, *args, **kwargs)


class ItemPage(Page):

    base_form_class = ItemPageForm
```

however, acquiring the "request" in the WagtailAdminPageForm constructor does not seem possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you want to override? From what you are asking it sounds like you want to change the queryset for a foreign key select?

Comment: @IainShelvington My question si about what I should override to modify the page when it is displayed to user in admin.

Comment: ModelAdmin is probably not what you want for this, it can be a bit confusing as ModelAdmin does provide a way to manage / edit pages but it is not the main way. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html might be what you need?

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Great idea, thanks for the effort. I have not known this option before. However, it is not enough - I modified my question to reflect your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit ambiguous, so it is not super clear exactly what you need.

**Interpreted question: When crediting (or editing) a page, I need access to the `request` to modify the initial values of some fields in the page form.**

### Potential Approach

Note: This may not be best practice and could be fragile depending on future changes to Wagtail.

First, we need a custom `EditHandler`, these are the way Wagtail builds up forms and even Panels within the editing interface. An `EditHandler`'s job is to manage the form to return based on the model and even the current request.

As a first step, it would be good to get your page create form showing correctly by following the instructions on using a custom tabbed interface. From here, you can replace the `TabbedInterface` with your custom class (e.g. `CustomTabbedInterface`) and add some functionality to this which will allow for a dynamic `form_class` to be returned.

`get_form_class` should return the `form_class`, however, we can modify it to return a function that, when called, will instantiate the class with custom information based on the request.

There may be some issues with this approach below in edit views or scenarios not considered by this example so validate this fully before using.

### Example Code

```py
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import TabbedInterface, ObjectList
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class CustomTabbedInterface(TabbedInterface):

    def get_form_class(self):
        form_class = super().get_form_class()
        request = self.request
        if request and request.method != 'POST':
            # check request is available to ensure this instance has been bound to it
            user = self.request.user

            def initiate_class(**kwargs):
                # instead of returning the class, return a function that returns the instantiated class
                # here we can inject a kwarg `initial` into the generated form
                # important: this gets called for edit view also and initial will override the instance data
                # kwarg['instance'] will be the `Page` instance and can be inspected as needed
                kwargs['initial'] = {'introduction': user.first_name}

                return form_class(**kwargs)

            return initiate_class

        return form_class


class StandardPage(Page):
    # ... field etc
    edit_handler = CustomTabbedInterface([
        ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'),
        ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading='Promote'),
        ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, heading='Settings', classname="settings"),
    ])
```

### Explanation

- [wagtail/admin/views/pages.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/2.9.x/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py#L218) contains the `create` view, which will use the `edit_handler`, bind it to the model and the request and then call its `get_form_class`.
- The `form_class` is used for the response here [`form = form_class(instance=page, parent_page=parent_page)`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/2.9.x/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py#L314)
- It gets called with the instance and the parent_page kwargs
- Our custom `get_form_class` response takes those kwargs and injects an additional `initial` kwarg.
- `initial` is used by Django forms to add any initial data - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values
- Finally, the Django form will merge the instance field values with the `intial` kwarg to generate the final pre-filled data for the form. You can see how this works in [Django's BaseModelForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L296).
- Be careful to consider what will happen on an update view, you likely do not want to override existing values with your initial values when a user has already entered something in the field.

Comment: Good job! It works on Wagtail 2.9. Note: it does not work with Wagtail 2.4 (self.request does not exist).

Comment: Good to know. That area of code has been in a bit of flux over the last little while. That is probably why the other question response you linked does not work.